# Watch Dog Timer

Tags: c++, c, timer, watchdog

Is there any way I can write code similar to WDT? If you have any suggestions or src code is much appreciated.I am not finding proper solution.

Answers I got on web are almost for specific chipsets. But I need similar to WDT kind of implementation. As we all know WDT is a counter that counts down from some initial value to zero. Before it hits minimum value program has to respond else a interrupt is fired.

```
int counter = reset_counter();
while(counter!=0) {
     // mode = return value of function which is boolean.
     if (mode) {
      // check return if true reset counter
      reset_counter();
     }
     counter--;

}
```

I dont know whether my code works properly!
Language I would like to use is C/C++.

Comment: "Language I would like to use is C/C++."  I am afraid there is no such language

Comment: Sry, first only saw the code and it could be c# ;) Corrected it.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't resist: C/C++ is not a language. It is either C or C++. Ah, good old comp.lang.c++ days ;-)

Comment: Under windows and C++, you might create service or separate process P1, the controlled process P2 will have to PostMessage to your P1 process otherwise it will be terminated or restarted.

Comment: C/C++ is when you use printf/scanf together with cout and vector:)

Comment: Is it for an embedded system? If yes, you should really use the one provided by that system and not try implementing one on your own.

Comment: WDT require hardware support, hence the chip-specific implementations.  WDT are only used on simple uC.  Once you have interrupts and multitasking OS with many threads, the WDT concept becomes increasingly inappropriate - where are you supposed to feed that dog when there are 75 processes with 1174 threads?

Comment: @luskan - 'he controlled process P2 will have to PostMessage to your P1 process otherwise it will be terminated or restarted' - then that becomes an added failure mechanism. Also, the P2 GUI may well be up and posting messages but the P2 database/network threads completely deadlocked.

Comment: Instead of posting messages, other concept can be used like named Events. I was dealing with such mechanism on WindowsCE, device was reseting itself if one function was not called frequently enough. So any to long loop and app is dead. In the end I ended up creating separate thread to just call this function. I suppose WDT is helpfull if your application hands up because of Data Abort, then device will reset application and user will be able to use software again. I suppose Visual Studio uses some kind of WDT mechanizm, when it hangs up it always restarts itself.

Comment: Hi Armen, luska, Christian.K, Martin James, I know that there is no such language as C/C++. What I mean by 'Language I would like to use is C/C++
' is either C or C++. Anyway thanks for all your replies.

Comment: @MartinJames Please do not leave "+1" comments that repeat the entire comment you're replying to. We already support a "+1" feature for comments—hover over the comment and click the up arrow in the left-hand margin. The tooltip says "this is a great comment", which is exactly the message you're apparently trying to send. Using this instead keeps down the noise and lets us actually *see* the useful/funny comments.

Comment: "I dont know whether my code works properly!" - have to tried running it?

Answer (score -1):

Are you wokring on an embedded system? Why not use a timer? Usually they count up ... but that doesn't matter. In the end it creates an interrupt on overflow.

To find out if your code works correctly you have to test it yourself.